# Not able to Identify xmlns:soap table-web element in selenuim

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How can we identify a table element which having

`xmlns:soap="http://url"` in it.
I tried with the below solution but it didnt work :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[namespace-uri()='http://**url**'][@class = 'selected']"));
```

Here is the **HTML code** :

```
<table xmlns:soap="schemas.xml***********a" xmlns:html="www.***********" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; height: 203px; table-layout: fixed;" objecttype="testenvironment" id="table_TestEnvironments" sort_col="name" sort_order="ascending" height="203px">
```

Comment: Relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace please

Comment: can you share the relevant HTML ?

Comment: <table xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xml***********a" xmlns:html="http://www.***********" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; height: 203px; table-layout: fixed;" objecttype="testenvironment" id="table_TestEnvironments" sort_col="name" sort_order="ascending" height="203px">